# stubbing `window.location.reload` for unit tests - "Some of your tests did a full page reload!"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have this in a controller:

```
   $scope.foo = function(){
      return RolesService.remove({
        data: role
      })
      .then(function (v) {
        if (!(v && v.cdtError)) {
          $window.location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
```

`$window` is injected into the controller

and then in my unit test:

```
 let $window = {location: {reload: sinon.spy()}};

  module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$window', $window);
    $window.onbeforeunload = sinon.spy();
  });
```

the above stub doesn't seem to do anything, because I still get this error:

> Some of your tests did a full page reload!

How can I stub `window.location.reload` so that this doesn't happen?

I see some stuff on the Karma Github issue tracker for this, but I can't find an answer.

Comment: maybe I cam calling `module()` in the wrong place, should I put that in a `beforeEach` hook?

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to do the trick:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    angular.mock.module('app', function ($provide) {
      let $window = {location: {reload: sinon.spy()}};
      $provide.value('$window', $window);
      $window.onbeforeunload = sinon.spy();
    });
  });
```